# Remove Microsoft Intune

Tags: android, git, cordova, intune

I recently added the Microsoft Intune plugin (https://github.com/msintuneappsdk/cordova-plugin-ms-intune-mam) to an Android app (built using Apache Cordova) that I am developing. I eventually decided I didn't actually want the plugin, so I attempted to remove it.

However, when I build my app I still get a message saying that I need to sign in to Intune in order to access the app. I'm not sure how to resolve this. I have tried:

- Removing the plugin through Cordova's config.xml plugins menu
- Uninstalling the app from my phone
- Rolling back my git repository to a commit prior to the download and installation of the plugin

I'm at a loss on what to do now. The fact that the Git reset didn't work makes me suspect that there's some other piece to the puzzle that I'm missing - something external to my app (maybe something related to the Intune service itself)?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve this issue by cleaning my solution in Visual Studio by going Build->Clean Solution, and by restarting my phone.